# Change icon of Windows 10 Quick Launch (Custom) Toolbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, user-folders, quicklaunch

I have created a quick launch toolbar of my Games folder (Right click taskbar → Toolbars → New Toolbar → Select Game Folder).

This creates a toolbar that looks like this:

[image: Snapshot]

I am trying to **change the icon of these folders on my toolbar**.

I have changed the icon of my folder on my disk, but that does not change the icon on the toolbar. I'm guessing the toolbar icons are shortcuts, but I can't find the location of the shortcuts on the disk.

All I can find is the disk location of the normal quick launch shortcuts:
`C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`

Any idea where the toolbar shortcuts are on disk? Or any suggestions?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem:**

When you created the toolbar, you selected a folder. If that folder has other folders inside, you will see folders on your toolbar.

**The fix:**

To fix this, create a folder specifically for your toolbar and create shortcuts to all your game executables (.exe files) like I have done for my creative tools.
[image: Shortcuts in a folder]

Create a new toolbar that points to the folder with all your new shortcuts in and your icons will appear.

[image: Final toolbar with icons]